# how can i make my code responsive for resizing page

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make the code for the simple main page.

There are sub1, sub2 for a

```css
 html, body, div, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ul, ol, li, dl, dt, dd, img, form, fieldset, input, textarea, blockquote {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                border: 0;
                width : 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
        .main_wrap {
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        .sub1 {
            display: inline-block;
            float: left;
            width: 49%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: #0a4e85;
            text-align: center;
            display: table;
            border: 5px solid white;
        }

        .sub2 {
            display: inline-block;
            float: left;
            width: 50%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: white;
            text-align: center;
            display: table;
            border: 5px solid #0a4e85;

        }
        .main_title1, .main_title2{
            color : white;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 1.55;
            white-space: nowrap;
            font-size: 70px;
            display: table-cell;
            vertical-align: middle;
            font-weight: 500;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
```

```html
 <html>
    <head>
        <title>Main</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="main_wrap">
        <div class="sub1"><div class="main_title1"><a href="javascript:goPageList();" >A</a></div></div>
        <div class="sub2"><div class="main_title2"><a href="javascript:goPageMonth();" style="color: #0a4e85" >B</div></div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

menu. Each div divide window vertically.

but when I reduce window width size, the second div which is sub2 goes below sub1.

I want to keep sub1,sub2 in line.
what can I do for fix it?

thanks!!

Comment: What do you regard as the minimum width the side-by-side `.sub1` and `.sub2` elements should have? At what point does it make sense for them to stop being side-by-side? If they hold content then remember that usability/clarity should override your desire to maintain a specific layout.

Answer (score 0):

Add `box-sizing: border-box;` in the body tag

```css
 html, body, div, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ul, ol, li, dl, dt, dd, img, form, fieldset, input, textarea, blockquote {
                    margin: 0;
                    padding: 0;
                    border: 0;
                    width : 100%;
                    height: 100%;
                    box-sizing: border-box;
                }
            .main_wrap {
                position: relative;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
            .sub1 {
                display: inline-block;
                float: left;
                width: 50%;
                height: 100%;
                background-color: #0a4e85;
                text-align: center;
                display: table;
                border: 5px solid white;
            }
        
            .sub2 {
                display: inline-block;
                float: left;
                width: 50%;
                height: 100%;
                background-color: white;
                text-align: center;
                display: table;
                border: 5px solid #0a4e85;
        
            }
            .main_title1, .main_title2{
                color : white;
                text-align: center;
                line-height: 1.55;
                white-space: nowrap;
                font-size: 70px;
                display: table-cell;
                vertical-align: middle;
                font-weight: 500;
                text-decoration: none;
            }
```

```html
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Main</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <div class="main_wrap">
            <div class="sub1"><div class="main_title1"><a href="javascript:goPageList();" >A</a></div></div>
            <div class="sub2"><div class="main_title2"><a href="javascript:goPageMonth();" style="color: #0a4e85" >B</div></div>
        </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: it' works till some point, but when i resize window to a minimum, sub2 still goes under sub1

Comment: in which resolution sub2 going down ?

Comment: It's going down at 630px!

Comment: i think code is working fine. plz have a look again.

Answer (score 0):

```css
 html, body, div, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ul, ol, li, dl, dt, dd, img, form, fieldset, input, textarea, blockquote {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                border: 0;
                width : 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
        .main_wrap {
            position: relative;
            display: flex;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        .sub1 {
            display: inline-block;
            float: left;
            width: 49%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: #0a4e85;
            text-align: center;
            display: table;
            border: 5px solid white;
        }

        .sub2 {
            display: inline-block;
            float: left;
            width: 50%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: white;
            text-align: center;
            display: table;
            border: 5px solid #0a4e85;

        }
        .main_title1, .main_title2{
            color : white;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 1.55;
            white-space: nowrap;
            font-size: 70px;
            display: table-cell;
            vertical-align: middle;
            font-weight: 500;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
```

```html
 <html>
    <head>
        <title>Main</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="main_wrap">
        <div class="sub1"><div class="main_title1"><a href="javascript:goPageList();" >A</a></div></div>
        <div class="sub2"><div class="main_title2"><a href="javascript:goPageMonth();" style="color: #0a4e85" >B</div></div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

You have just added the display: flex; in main_wrap class.